# How can I bundle my plugin for Three.js plugin with Webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm creating a Three.js plugin with typescript.
I need to bundle them to make them possible to use easily.

```
import * as THREE from "three";

export default class MyPlugin{
   public something: THREE.Quaternion;
}
```

Even I refer them as just a type, I need to include the sentence `import * as THREE from "three";`. By this code, webpack will bundle all of three.js code.

I would like to use this plugin as separated javascript file. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: List `three.js` as a peer dependency?

Comment: I haven't added three as a peer dependency. I will confirm your suggestion later. But, I don't think webpack will resolve three dependency from window when It is listed as peer dependency at this time.